# gitlab - unable to cleanly delete/remove directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to using git and using gitlab. I'm having issues cleaning up a directory after removing the project from the web interface.

First I "remove project" and the project was removed. Then I went to directory of where the folder is located and tried doing an `rm -rf <directory>` and got the following messages:

```
$ rm -rf data_warehouse/
rm: data_warehouse//.git/objects/01/434330a1f2411755e0dfd402dc9c7ab9258bc6: Operation not permitted
rm: data_warehouse//.git/objects/01/7c41807d3e1ea1b6f53ea0450355a817000b07: Operation not permitted
rm: data_warehouse//.git/objects/01: Directory not empty

$ cd data_warehouse/
$ ls
```

If a `cd` into directory `data_warehouse` there are no files. So the directory is empty. Why can't I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a practical answer, smash that folder into oblivion with:

```
sudo rm -rf data_warehouse
```

As o11c pointed out, if you use `sudo` to create stuff, you often need to use `sudo` to get rid of stuff. [Here's an intro to Unix file permissions](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml) which may be helpful reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ls` in a directory, it will only list files whose names do not start with a dot.

Use `ls -a` to list all files in a directory.

The `Operation not permitted` error looks like you once did something in this repository as a different user. Such errors are common if, for example, you carelessly use `sudo`.